# c++ vector push_back pointer from iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, containers, intellisense

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>
struct struct_ {};
class class_ {
public:
    std::vector<struct_*>vectorStructPointers;

};
std::set<class_>setClass;
std::vector<struct_>vectorStruct;
int main() {
    auto itvs = vectorStruct.begin();
    auto itsc=setClass.begin();
    itsc->vectorStructPointers.push_back(&*itvs);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1087   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=struct_ *, _Alloc=std::allocator<struct_ *>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)  P1  
P1\Simplify.cpp 14
```

staring at this for hours.
Don't understand:
1)std::allocator
2)what's wrong with my push_back.

please help.

Answer (score 3):

Elements of a `std::set` are `const` and may not be modified.

So `itsc->vectorStructPointers` is also `const` and `push_back` can't be called on it, since it is a non-`const` member function.

The error message hints at that: `the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match` (the type qualifier being `const`)

If you want to modify elements, you can't use `std::set`. It is supposed to keep elements ordered, so modifying them can't be allowed.